# Arduino not picking up analog reading 20 meter away from my pressure sensor

Tags: arduino, sensor, serial, distance, pressure

I’m new here. I just hooked up my 3-pin (5V, GND, Analog Out) **XGZP6847020KPG** pressure sensor right on my Arduino pro mini (at first it was not working, then I added a 10 kOhm resistor in parallel with the analog out to ground).

[image]

I wrote the code and read the analog value (0.67 V) off my serial monitor, as I applied pressure the analog value also changed which seemed okay. But since the sensor will be monitoring my water tank level it means I will have to connect the sensor at least 20 meter away from the controller. After connecting the cable I turned on the serial monitor but the value remained constant (at 0.42 V). What could be the cause of this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhYzLu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: show us the whole circuit. How have you connected the pressure sensor? It should share the 0V and 5V with the Arudino

Comment: the sensor is not expected to be run via a 20m wire. You might want to reconsider your choice of sensor or your physical design.

Comment: The sensor works with longer distance. I think I just didn't connect it properly. I connected pin 2 to Arduino RAW pin, while pin 1 goes to GND and pin 5 goes to Analog pin A0. Lastly, how do I post pictures here in the comment section (if it's possible)?

Comment: Pardon me, but I can't seem to figure out how to post pictures/schematics here in the comment section

Comment: you can't. edit the post

Comment: and your guess about connecting it poorly sounds likely; btw I have no idea what Arduino RAW pin is, but I assume it's PWR

Comment: This sensor is designed for dry air. Is water contacting the sensor? If so you may have damaged the sensor. Show a complete wiring diagram (the conductors you are using in the cable are important). What's the current consumption of the sensor? It's not listed in the spec sheet. What wire gauge are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found out what the problem was. I removed the 10kOhm resistor that I initially used as a pull-down resistor, I found out it was conflicting with the internally built 5kOhm resistor, so the long wire had a huge voltage drop . It's working fine now.

Comment: @Ilya the RAW pin is on the Arduino Pro mini controller, it has an in-built voltage regulator so it can take between 5 and 6 volts DC, it is different from the Vcc pin which takes strictly 5 volts DC

Answer (score 2):

Datasheet, page 6:

Other handling precautions

▼That using the wrong pressure range or mounting method may result in accidents.

▼**The only direct pressure medium you can use is dry air**. The use of other media, in particular,
corrosive gases (organic solvent based gases, sulfurous acid based gases, and hydrogen sulfide
based gases, etc.) and **media that contains moisture or foreign substances will cause
malfunction and damage**. Please do not use them.

EDIT: to make it clear, your device can't work in water and may very well be already dead

Comment: I didn't immerse the sensor in water, I only connected a dry  pvc hose to the sensor and used the pressure applied by the level rise of the water to increase air pressure in the hose. So there is no physical contact between the sensor and the water

Comment: so what exactly is its purpose? It can't measure anything useful for you; as for why it doesn't work, please, present full schematic. With module pins and power.

Comment: Its purpose is to control water level. Theoretically, increase in the water volume/height also increases the air pressure in the hose linearly which the sensor senses and transfers the analog reading to the Arduino

Comment: alright, I think I got what you mean. Maybe your idea will work. In any case, present full schematic. It could be something with power too. In fact, it most likely is. I would measure voltage on power rails of the sensor module. Also, it shouldn't matter much because the sensor uses very little current, but a wire of that length has noticeable non-zero resistance. And capacitance. You might want to put a resistor right on the output pin. Some 1k or 10k, because sensors don't like driving capacitive loads

Comment: Please how do I post pictures/schematics here in the comment section

Comment: @ChukwumaCollinsEzenyinwa Put the schematic in your original post.